# Run input demanding programs (like CLI file editors) through PHP on a WebServer

Tags: php, html, linux, bash, server

I have a linux server and I am creating a remote terminal system.
I have the index.html file on the server along with php scripts to execute the commands and return the output (using Server Sent Events).
Everything works perfectly, except some commands.

ex.
**sudo apt-get update works perfectly** (and returns realtime output).
**sudo nano test.txt** does not return any output (I have a test.txt file with something written in it).

So, the question is, **how to execute commands like sudo nano** (and vi also I suppose) **in php and get back (echo) the interface of the program.**

I know about exec(), shell_exec(), system(), popen() but I can't get it.
I also know that I will need websockets in the future to respond back to these programs but I want to get the nano interface showing up first.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I believe I'll have to use proc_open but I can't get it to work. (I'm currently using popen)

Comment: Why not simply use SSH?

Comment: Well, many reasons! The whole idea is a web-terminal system which will be more portable and easier to interact. I also don't want to use a pre-made solution (like wetty) for UI and mainly performance reasons. And after all, as I mentioned, my solution is almost completed.